# How does Get method fits in domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design, nservicebus

Currently I am learning Domain Driven Design. Based on my understanding I have created a sample application which does some operations on country.

I have crated a class library named "MyTest.Country" which contains all commands-

```
--MyTest.Country (ProjectName)
     -- Commands (Folder)
        --CreateCountry (: ICommand)
        --DeleteCountry (: ICommand)
```

I have another class library named "MyTest.CountryClient" which interacts with the database using EF.

```
--MyTest.CountryClient (Project)
  --CountryClass  (ClassFile)
    --CreateCountry (Method)
    --DeleteCountry (Method)
    --GetAllCountryList (Method)
```

Yet another classlibrary for services named "MyTest.CountryServices" which contains the handler.

```
  --MyTest.CountryServices (Project)
      --CountryHandler : IHandleMessages<CreateCountry>
                       : IHandleMessages<DeleteCountry>
```

I have a web API which sends command to "MyTest.CountryServices" using NServiceBus for creating or Deleting the country. The message is handled by CountryHandler and then it invokes the respective method from "MyTestCountryClient".

I know that Country is an entity and cannot be defined as a domain. However, I am only trying to implement the DDD.

My question here is -

1. Am I following the proper DDD principles here?
2. If I want to get all country list, should I directly call MyTest.CountryClient? or I need to call services first even for the fetching operation?

Comment: Take a look at Udi's talk on the subject here: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1806-talk-from-udi-dahan

Comment: I agree with fabriciorissetto, you are missing the repository pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the `CountryClient` seems to be your `Repository`. If so, yes you can call it directly.

I suggest you start into DDD with the [building blocks](http://culttt.com/2014/09/15/defining-building-blocks-domain-driven-design/). And do not dig into Messages and Commands in the beggining.